# how to fix my for code in java, not working

Tags: java

Program that accepts integers and stores them in an array, and outputs the largest number of them.
but following code is not working

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.print("input the array'size : ");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int size = sc.nextInt();
int arr[]=new int[size];


System.out.print("input the array'value :");
for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
    int var = sc.nextInt();
    arr[i] = var; 
}

System.out.print("inputed value: ");
for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
System.out.print(arr[i]+ " ");
}

int max = 0;
for(int j=0; j<size; j++){
    if(max<arr[j+1]){
    max = arr[j];   
    }
    else {
    continue;
    }
}
System.out.println("the largest number in array :"+ max);
}
```

}

Comment: That logic makes no sense. When max is smaller than number X (i+1), then assign number Y (i) ... huh?

Comment: thank you sir!!! i find problem!! if(max<arr[j+1]) -> if(max < arr[j]). lt is working :)

Comment: Since this question is based on a mere typo, I would suggest to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop through array again to find Max value. By taking input itself we can get the max number by comparing with each input.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.print("input the array'size : ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int size = sc.nextInt();
    int arr[]=new int[size];
    System.out.println("input the array'value :");
    int max = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
      int var = sc.nextInt();
      arr[i] = var; 
      if(var > max) {
          max = var;
      }
    }
    System.out.print("Input Array: "+Arrays.toString(arr));
    System.out.println("The largest number in array :"+ max);
 }
```